# React Native: Orientation does not change on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using Expo. In google it says to enable both portrait and landscape modes, it's enough to remove "orientation" prop in app.json -> "expo" : { ..."orientation": ... } or set it to "orientation": "default". I have tried both. On Android both approaches work. On iOS none of them work. Rotating the emulator has no effect on the orientation.

**iOS:**
[image]

**Android:**
[image]

I have also tried using package https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/ and set

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "requireFullScreen": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-screen-orientation",
        {
          "initialOrientation": "DEFAULT"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

as described in the docs. This also has no effect for iOS. The rotation on the emulator itself works, checked with changing orientation in iOS maps.

I am using empty project generated by expo. Here orientation: default can be seen. The expo-screen-orientation is not in the project as it does not help and first approach should be enough to make it work.

**App.js:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**app.json:**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "default",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the problem and how to fix it?